# how to refer to columns within function?

Tags: r

I am a bit confused with all the different possibilities there are to refer to columns in a function. Can anyone explain when to use "enquo()" and "!!colname" or toString(colname)? And sometimes I have to use version1 (see below) or version2? In this example, only version1 works..

```
test <- data.frame(
  county = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  numbers = c(1,2,3,4))


function_x <- function(dataframe,columnname) {
  #1 b = enquo(columnname) 
  sum(dataframe[, toString(columnname)])
  #2 sum(dataframe[, !!columnname])
}


function_x(test, "numbers") # version1
function_x(test, numbers) # version2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `[` to select column version 1 would work without `toString` :

```
function_x <- function(dataframe,columnname) {
  sum(dataframe[, columnname])
}

function_x(test, "numbers")
#[1] 10
```

You cannot directly pass unquoted variables (version 2) to select columns.

```
function_x <- function(dataframe,columnname) {
  cols <- deparse(substitute(columnname))
  sum(dataframe[, cols])
}

function_x(test, numbers) 
#[1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `tidyverse` which can take both string and unquoted arguments

```
library(dplyr)
function_x <- function(dataframe, columnname) {
      dataframe %>%
            summarise(out = sum(!! rlang::ensym(columnname))) %>%
            pull(out)
 }
```

-testing

```
function_x(test, numbers)
#[1] 10
function_x(test, "numbers")
#[1] 10
```